# Using PTR on SPF Record and Multiple Domain Pointing Single Server

Tags: email-server, spf, ptr-record

Today I've checked my SPF is valid on some of the sites and invalid on some of the sites I've tested.

Microsoft also couldn't see my SPF record for some reason while others can. 
([Sender ID Framework SPF Record Wizard](https://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/default.aspx) )

I have mail server by my own, no hosting etc. This IP has PTR record pointing to mail.sonet.com.tr

My SFP record is below;

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr a:mail.****.com.tr ip4:195.***.***.*** mx:mail.*****.com.tr mx:webmail.*****.com.tr include:mail.*****.com.tr ~all
```

I get a warning from [Email Security Grader](http://www.emailsecuritygrader.com/results?id=1230897)

Should I be using ptr:mail.*****.com.tr or only ptr is enough?

Also I have 2 domains pointing this mail server,

I have set MX and A correctly with regarding to topics in Serverfault.com. My question is, do I have to set another PTR record for the other domain?

Comment: Currently I see `"v=spf1 a mx ip4:104.31.92.29 ip4:104.31.93.29 ip4:195.175.83.158 ~all"` as TXT for `sonet.com.tr`, not what you posted above. The first two IPs don't have PTRs, and the last is obsolete.

Comment: @sebix I updated NS to Cloudflare, added only ips and it worked. But when I try to add ptr, it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[emailsecuritygrader.com](http://emailsecuritygrader.com) reports you have a syntax error at your SPF record.

Take a look to this: http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax